# Account level , daily rolling average Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I opened a similar question late last year on the forum but wanted to see if someone could help me adjust the output I received from that question to be a bit more specific.

I have the following raw data, where there are multiple accounts for each date:

| Date | Account | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/26/2023 | AAA | 497 |
| 12/26/2023 | BBB | 328 |
| 12/26/2023 | CCC | 398 |
| 12/22/2023 | AAA | 997 |
| 12/22/2023 | BBB | 709 |
| 12/22/2023 | CCC | 943 |
| 12/21/2023 | AAA | 825 |
| 12/21/2023 | CCC | 130 |
| 12/20/2023 | AAA | 275 |

The first question was about ignoring the individual accounts and summing the values by day to create a daily rolling average.

To do that, I was advised to create the below two measures.

```
DailySum = SUM('Table'[Value])

AvgDaily = 
  var thisDate = MAX('Table'[Date])
  var lastN = 
    TOPN(10,
      SUMMARIZE(
        FILTER(ALL('Table'), 'Table'[Date] <= thisDate),
        'Table'[Date],
        "Sum", [Value]
      ),
      [Date], DESC
    )
  return IF(COUNTROWS(lastN) = 10, AVERAGEX(lastN, [Sum]) )
```

Now, however, I'm at the point where I'd like to take into consideration the account without ignoring it, as in the above.

The idea would be that the rolling average would be specific to account.

For example, RollingAvg for AAA on 12/26 would be (497+997+825)/3. In the interest of the potential for missing data, maybe it's possible to revert to summing last three instances instead of last 3 dates explicitly. I'm not sure, but I'm hoping someone might be able to help me in terms of how to adjust the above code to include accounts accordingly.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `ALL(...)` with `ALLEXCEPT(...)` so that it keeps `Account` in the context.

```
AvgDaily = 
  var thisDate = MAX('Table'[Date])
  var lastN = 
    TOPN(10,
      SUMMARIZE(
        FILTER(
          ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Account]),
          'Table'[Date] <= thisDate
        ),
        'Table'[Date],
        "Sum", [Value]
      ),
      [Date], DESC
    )
  return IF(COUNTROWS(lastN) = 10, AVERAGEX(lastN, [Sum]) )
```

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate the help. I'm going to test a bit later but I think this should do it. Just to be clear, the FILTER argument is the key here because the calculation will only be run on the table created by the FILTER command, correct? And we're just adding back the account column to that table (whereas it wasn't there in the first version of this script)?